# Android Selected item at center in listview

Tags: android, listview

all

I've spent a lot of time for doing this.
What I want to do is that selected item is position at center row in listview.
For example, there are 10 items. It looks move an item not focus. Focus is always at center. I use remote control, not smartphone, it's impossible to use touch event. Can you give me some tips? How to do that? Save my time, please

### 1

### 2

### 3 <- Focus

### 4

### 5

Key up

### 2

### 3

### 4 <- Focus

### 5

### 6

Comment: Are you able to accomplish this in smartphone ?

Comment: no I didn't do in a smartphone.

Comment: And what will be the difference in doing this in smartphone and remote as you are telling.

Comment: It's only different is that touch event and key event. The point is that I didn't do that, even smart phone

Answer (score 0):

You can do this way:

```
int x = (listView.getAdapter().getCount())/2;

listView.setSelection(x);
listView.getSelectedView().setSelected(true);
```

and when you what to move increment or decrement x, and of course set the element as selected

Answer (score 0):

As you've mentioned in the comment that you didn't try this in smartphone as well, So You can do something like this,

```
int listHeight = listView.getHeight();
int rowHeight = rowView.getHeight();    
listView.setSelectionFromTop(position, listHeight /2 - rowHeight /2);
```

Hope your remote control will also work fine.